# Weird indy redirect post

Tags: delphi, post, delphi-2010, indy

I'm trying to send a post request using Indy but I am facing some problems.
In a form I have TIdHTTP, a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and a TIdCookieManager whith these properties:

*TIdHTTP:*

```
IdHTTP1.IOHandler := FSSLIO;
IdHTTP1.AllowCookies := True;
IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentLength := -1;
IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';
IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions := [hoKeepOrigProtocol, hoForceEncodeParams];
IdHTTP1.OnRedirect := IdHTTP1Redirect;
IdHTTP1.CookieManager := IdCookieManager1;
```

*TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL:* default values

*TIdCookieManager:* default values

*OnRedirect procedure:*

```
Handled := True;
```

In a button the following request:

```
Params := TStringStream.Create('asdf=asdf',TEncoding.UTF8);    
edtmemo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.detran.mg.gov.br/habilitacao/1-habilitacao-quero-ser-condutor/consultar-resultado-exame-legislacao/-/busca_resultado_exames/', Params);
Params.Free;
```

But returns error with response code 301, but the wierd part is that the location is the same url that I am trying to send, so it enter in an infinite loop.

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 31 Aug 2017 20:23:32 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
P3P: CP="A politica de privacidade deve estar disponivel no site ou pode ser solicitada via fale conosco."
Set-Cookie: SECCCAKEPHP=e19ttp30m5380ih41qal0gipg2; expires=Sat, 09-Sep-2017 04:23:32 GMT; path=/
Location: https://www.detran.mg.gov.br/habilitacao/1-habilitacao-quero-ser-condutor/consultar-resultado-exame-legislacao/-/busca_resultado_exames/
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Expires: Thu, 07 Sep 2017 20:23:32 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Curl test:

```
curl -vv -X POST -F 'asdf=asdf' https://www.detran.mg.gov.br/habilitacao/1-habilitacao-quero-ser-condutor/consultar-resultado-exame-legislacao/-/busca_resultado_exames/
```

I tried the same request using curl and works with response code 200.
Any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: The server is redirecting to the same URL, but it is also sending a cookie that was likely missing in the initial request. This is reasonable behavior if the server wants that cookie back. If the server gets stuck in an endless redirect loop, that is a different issue. Sniff the traffic to see what curl sends vs what `TIdHTTP` sends. To sniff curl's HTTPS traffic, you can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). To sniff `TIdHTTP`'s HTTPS traffic, you can assign a `TIdLog...` component, such as `TIdLogFile`, to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property. Does `TIdHTTP` send back that cookie?

Comment: What command-line parameters are you passing to curl? What `Params` are you passing to `TIdHTTP.Post()`?  Please provide a [mcve] showing everything you are actually doing to reproduce the issue. Also, Delphi 2010 is 8 years old, are you using an equally old version of Indy? At the time of this writing, the current Indy version is 10.6.2.5434.

Comment: I edited the question, added the curl request, and with those parameters curl doesn't handle redirects, but responds with a 200 code.
The only way I could simulate the same problem in curl is if instead of https I use http.
And yes, I know that Delphi 2010 is old and yes I use version 10.5.5 of Indy, we already tried to update, at least Indy, but we faced a LOT o problems and unfortunately we do not have enough time or people to deal with it.

Comment: Your `TIdHTTP` logic does not match you curl logic. I posted an answer explaining the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [curl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), you will see that the `-F` option posts data in `multipart/form-data` format:

> **-F, --form**
>
> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. **This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to [RFC 2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)**. This enables uploading of binary files etc.

However, your `TIdHTTP` code is posting data that is in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format instead.  And more importantly, you are not setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType` property to `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` to match the data.  If you post a `TStream`, you have to set the `ContentType` accordingly.

`TIdHTTP` prefers `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data to be posted using a `TStrings`-derived object (like `TStringList`) instead of a `TStream`, so it can ensure the data is encoded and formatted correctly, eg:

```
var
  Params: TStringList;
begin
  ...
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.Add('asdf=asdf'); // <-- DO NOT url-encode the values here!
    // the TStrings version of Post() will set the Request.ContentType
    // to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' by default...
    edtmemo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.detran.mg.gov.br/habilitacao/1-habilitacao-quero-ser-condutor/consultar-resultado-exame-legislacao/-/busca_resultado_exames/', Params);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

`TIdHTTP` prefers `multipart/form-data` data to be posted using a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` object instead (unless you pass it another `TStream` that contains pre-formatted MIME data in it).

So, to match what your curl command is sending, try this instead:

```
uses
  ..., IdMultipartFormData;

var
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  ...
  Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    Params.AddFormField('asdf', 'asdf', 'utf-8');
    // the TIdMultipartFormDataStream version of Post() will set the
    // Request.ContentType to 'multipart/form-data' with a suitable
    // MIME 'boundary' attribute for you...
    edtmemo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.detran.mg.gov.br/habilitacao/1-habilitacao-quero-ser-condutor/consultar-resultado-exame-legislacao/-/busca_resultado_exames/', Params);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @remy-lebeau for the answer, tried your suggestion but unfortunately does not worked. Now it sends with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------090117161550011`. But same result

Comment: Using the current version of Indy with the exact code you showed in your question, I cannot reproduce the issue. Without making any of the changes I suggested in my answer, the server replies with 200 containing an HTML document, instead of replying with a 301 redirect.  So, you need to do what I originally suggested: "*Sniff the traffic to see what curl sends vs what TIdHTTP sends*". There is clearly something in (or missing from) the TIdHTTP request on your machine that the server does not like. Anything curl sends, `TIdHTTP` can replicate with the right coding

Comment: I tried to use Fiddler, I think it may be some problem with SSL, because in the fiddler tries to `CONNECT` to the server, and returns 408 bad request.

Comment: `CONNECT` is the traditional way to tunnel an HTTPS connection through an HTTP proxy, and `CONNECT` will NOT be sent to the target server. An HTTPS client (like curl), configured to connect to an HTTP proxy (such as with curl's `-x` option), would connect to Fiddler (the proxy) and ask it to `CONNECT` a TCP connection to the target server. Once the TCP connection is established, the client would then negotiate an SSL/TLS session directly with the target server, before then sending its HTTP request directly to the target server. The server will not know a proxy is involved.

Comment: [Fiddler is able to debug HTTPS](https://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp). When the client tries to negotiate an SSL/TLS session with the target server, Fiddler intercepts the request and pretends to be the target server by sending its own SSL/TLS reply to the client (as such, the client must accept Fiddler's certificate if it performs certificate validation, otherwise the negotiation fails and the connection is closed), and then Fiddler pretends to be the client to negotiate an SSL/TLS session with the target server, and then passes data between the two sessions.

Comment: At no point in this process is `CONNECT` ever sent to the target server, unless the client is misconfigured into thinking the target server is a proxy.

Comment: Once again, thks for your response and for the patience explain the concepts, the only thing I did was change the TIdHTTP and the curl to use the Fiddler proxy, curl worked, indy doesn´t :(

Comment: `TIdHTTP` supports HTTP proxies, via its `ProxyParams` property. I know it works. But it is also not necessary in this situation. As I stated in an earlier comment: "*To sniff `TIdHTTP`'s HTTPS traffic, you can assign a `TIdLog...` component, such as `TIdLogFile`, to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property*". Indy has several `TIdLog...` components available (`TIdLogDebug`, `TIdLogFile`, `TIdLogEvent`, `TIdLogStream`). No proxy needed.